# Confusion about all() and any() functions

Tags: python, syntax

I'm learning python and experiencing some confusion with understanding `all()` and `any()` functions:

```
1 in [0,2]             #False. Correct.
all([0,1]) in [0,2]    #True. Why? 1 is not in [0,2]
any([0,1]) in [0,2]    #False. Why? 0 is in [0,2]
```

Comment: all means " && and " operator and any means " || or " operator. when applying to the list it will apply the operator between elements of a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`all([0,1])` returns `False` (because the "truthiness" of 0 is defined to be `False`) and `False in [0,2]` returns `True` (for quite similar reasons).

Probably you were intending to say something like

```
any(x in [0,1] for x in [0,2])  # True
all(x in [0,1] for x in [0,2])  # False
```

Answer (score 2):

Function `all()` returns bolean `True` if all items in iterable object are `True` and `False` if any is `False`:

```
all([0, 1]) # return True if all items are True
```

return `False` because `0` is considered as `False`
and when `False in [0, 2]` returns `True`, because `0 == False`.

For `any([0,1]) in [0,2]    #False. Why? 0 is in [0,2]`

```
any([0,1]) # return True if any item is True
```

returns `True` because `1 = True`.

Then it checks `True in [0, 2]` and there is no `True` or `1` in `[0, 2]` and it returns `False`.

```
In [1]: 1 == True                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[1]: True

In [2]: 0 == False                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[2]: True

In [3]: 2 == True                                                                                                                                                                                           
Out[3]: False
```

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand how your expressions are calculated. First of all, note that `0` is falsy, and `1` is truthy. `all([0,1])` is `False` because not all elements are truthy. `any([0,1])` is `True` because some elements are truthy. Then you look for the membership of `False` and `True` in `[0, 2]`. When taken as a number, `True` has a value of `1` and `False` has a value of `0`. Thus, `False in [0, 2]` evaluates to `True` because `False == 0` is `True`, so `False` was "found" in `[0, 2]`. In the same way, `True` is not found, so you get `False` for the second expression.

Usually, `all` and `any` are not directly used on lists; using them with generators is very common. For example,

```
any(x in [0, 2] for x in [0, 1]) # "is any of [0, 1] in [0, 2]?"
all(x in [0, 2] for x in [0, 1]) # "is all of [0, 1] in [0, 2]?"
```

Answer (score 0):

in python, the truthiness of Zero, empty `list`, `None` are defined as false

```
    1 in [0,2]             #False. Correct.
    all([0,1]) in [0,2]    #True. Why? 1 is not in [0,2]
    any([0,1]) in [0,2]    #False. Why? 0 is in [0,2]


    all([None,1]) in [None,2]    #False.
    any([[],1]) in [[],2]    #False.
```